# Keep my version of a conflicting file with subversive

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

i am using subversive as eclipse svn plugin
and i have a question, that when updating from repository you may get a file conflict
and i want to keep my version of the conflicting file and ignore merging (ignore the updates on this file/don't update this file), how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the file / mark as merged.

Comment: i did that but the file still contains stuff like:` =======    
>>>>>>> .r21` and also merged the other changes from repository.